# Filtrar un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Como puedo filtrar un array por 2 parámetros donde Key es el criterio de búsqueda, “nombre”, “municipio”, “departamento” y value es el valor a buscar eje: “antioquia”

llevo hasta el momento esto

```
const sitiosEcoturisticos = [{
nombre = "parque el poblado",
municipio = "medellin",
departmento = "antioquia",
latitud = 5.25,
longitud = 10.5 ,
estrellas = 10 
 }]

 const filtarResultados = (key, value) => {
 var clave = document.getElementById("key").value;
 var valor = document.getElementById("value").value;
 valor = valor.toLower.Case();

 const result = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
   (sitios) => sitios == clave && sitios == valor
 );
 console.log(result);
  };
```

Comment: Faltaría un ejemplo de como es la estructura de `sitiosEcoturisticos` al menos.

Comment: @Emeeus ya hice la corrección de la estructura

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtro = {clave:"departamento", valor:"antoquia"};

const result = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
   (sitios) => sitios.clave == filtro.clave && sitios.valor == filtro.valor
);
```

Esto podría servir de ejemplo si el arreglo sitiosEcoturisticos fuera un array de objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener  valores de los inputs te seria de utilidad este link

[manejo de formularios](https://manuais.iessanclemente.net/index.php/Manejo_de_formularios_con_JavaScript)

> De la forma que codificaste el filter no puede comparar

```js
const sitiosEcoturisticos = [{
    nombre : "parque el poblado",
municipio : "medellin",
departmento : "antioquia",
latitud : 5.25,
longitud : 10.5 ,
estrellas : 10 
}];

let clave="parque el poblado";
let value=10;
 const result = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
   (sitios) => sitios.nombre == clave && sitios.estrellas == value
 );
 console.log(result);
```